# Force trailing slash in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Force https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

What can I do to force a trailing slash when there isn't one? For instance, my current URLs look like this:

`https://amemoirproject.com/chapters/quarter-after`

I'd like to force a trailing slash so they look like this:

`https://amemoirproject.com/chapters/quarter-after/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond` makes sure that there isn't any files with that name. If there is not, it adds the trailing slash.